# Does ubuntu have a control-alt-delete like in windows where I can recover from a frozen screen?

Tags: freeze

My system occasionally freezes when I am watching a video.

I have to perform a hard reboot. Does ubuntu 20.x have some sort of control-alt-delete where I can kill the process or restart it like windows does?

My mouse still works, but no response to any clicks and keyboard doesn't work.

Comment: What mostly works is switching to a console (Ctrl + Alt + F3...F7), logging in, and killing the runaway process.

Comment: how do I get out of console?

Comment: How much RAM and swap do you have? Read `man free mkswap swapon`. By adding several megabytes of swap, you might avoid the problem altogether.

Comment: @waltinator I have 64GB ram...more than enough!

Comment: @waltinator it shows I have 2097148 total swap currently using the 'free' command.

Comment: You get back to the graphic screen with Ctrl + Alt + F2.

Comment: Try Alt + F2 `killall` or `xkill`.

Comment: if you have a compiz setup you can go to the compizconfig settings and under the general section you can setup commands I have used it to make Ctrl + Alt + delete open system monitor with system monitor (and programs like it) you can kill processes like in windows task manger. you can use it to make a shortcut to reset the system as well

Comment: @waltinator is that enough swap that I have?

Answer (score 4):

1. Open a text-only virtual console by using the keyboard shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> (or Ctrl+Alt+<kbd>F3</kbd>-<kbd>F6</kbd>).
2. At the `login:` prompt type your username and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
3. At the `Password:` prompt type your user password and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.
4. Logout of your current desktop session.

   ```
    gnome-session-quit
   ```
5. To bring up the normal Ubuntu login screen run this command:

   ```
   sudo systemctl start graphical.target
   ```